# Speed optimization involving a lot of matrices generated in C/C++ - storing in a file vs recomputing

Tags: c, performance, pointers

This is the 'need to know details about the problem': As a part of an algorithm I am coding, it takes as an input a matrix of size 3000X400. For every row, I need to create a square matrix, ie of size 400x400. After I do this, I need to calculate a number  R(i,j) where i,j are the square matrices(400x400) that have been generated for every row.

Think of it as the computation of a correlation matrix if you will. instead of correlation I have my own algorithm that operates on square matrices generated. I have to compute R(i,j) for 0<=i<3000 and j=i+1 to 3000

Here is my question: I dynamically allocate a 3D array which points to a square matrix ie my 3d array is (3000X400X400). I don't have enough memory to do this. For smaller sizes ie around (800*400*400) I have code that works perfectly. But clearly not enough memory to extend it to (3000*400) case. How do I do this?

One(not-so-great)solution: Instead of computing every square matrix, what I do is, compute square matrix for i, and then when I loop around j = i+1 to 3000, I recompute the square matrices for each j and then calculate R(i,j). Clearly, I am recomputing a whole bunch of matrices, but atleast it is code that works.

Are there are faster solutions that you guys can think of? I am competent enough that a qualitative solution will be enough. 
I was thinking about computing the square matrices and writing them to files and reading them as and when I need to compute R(i,j) - will this be faster than recomputing solution I gave?

Thanks for the advice!!

The solution using writing to a file and reading from it was way slower. Any nonhadoop ideas anyone?

Comment: Sounds like a good application for Hadoop.  You should be able to parallelize the snot out of it.  You'll end up with results on disk, which you can then manipulate one matrix at a time.

Comment: Sorry, what is hadoop? Also, do you think there is no better way than reading and writing from a file?

Comment: Almost any optimization problem is going to have an answer that sounds like: try both methods, and see which one's faster. Use a profiler, preferably.

And Hadoop is pretty widely known and publicized. Searching on that name will provide LOTS of information.

Comment: Instead of allocating memory and letting OS do swapping, you should perhaps use memory mapped file on a 64 bit machine. Then it becomes a problem of arranging the calculation so, that disk cache of OS works effectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sparse matrices (lots of zeroes), you might consider alternate matrix representation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix for some inspiration).

If not, is there any way you can rewrite your algorithm such that you can compute a few (or even just one) of the square matrices, use them, and then discard them without needing them again?  Without knowing your application, I can't really say if that would work. But it's a thought.

Otherwise, consider other options. You might consider increasing your swap partition size (Linux) or Pagefile size (Windows). I'm not sure what it's called on OSX, but I'm sure there's a way to do it.  Basically, this is the space where the operating system writes little bits of memory onto the hard disk if it runs out of memory.  It's effectively writing your values to disk and reading them back again later, but the OS handles it and it'll be easier and slightly more efficient. Keep in mind that you'll probably need a 64-bit system in order to do this -- you're asking for upwards of three and a half gigabytes of contiguous address space and a 32-bit system would be hard-pressed to provide this.

If all else fails, if you have a 64-bit system and can afford it, you could always just buy more memory.

Good luck!

Comment: The thing is, definitely not a sparse matrix and I know for sure all the matrices I generate are completely full with nonzero values. Very low probability that it is zero. They are sort of distance matrices and the idea is to compute them and discard them. But like I explained in the problem, I dont have enough memory to store every computed matrix. Which is why i am recomputing and losing out so much time. :(.
I have a 64 bit system - about increasing the pagefile size. I wonder if there is a way to increase the page file size just for this program ? stack space just for the program?

Comment: I've ordered more memory and now I have about 12 gb of memory at my disposal, which I hope is enough. I need to look into seeing if there an equicalent Xmx or Xms command for my program like for java

Comment: The pagefile is a system-level thing -- basically, it lets the system pretend that a file on disk is actually ram, and then allocates it accordingly. As far as I know, compilers / C standard libraries don't artificially limit the memory you can use; if you drop 12gb of memory into the system, you should be able to use most of it in your program.  Hopefully that's enough to make your program work. Good luck!

Comment: yea, that was my hope as well, banking on more memory. thanks for the help!!

Comment: I have 12 gb memory now and it chokes halfway through by simply quitting. :(. The code works well and correctly for lower values. On a matrix of size 1000X400 it stops working and just quits. Task manager shows that i have plenty of memory left. Running it ona  windows machine using code blocks

Comment: So, I rewrote the code with c++ with a try-catch block and I've gotten bad_alloc error. But with task manager I see that the program onlu used around 2gn of memory. How do I get the program to use more memory?